# Growth of polynomial with power $< 1$ vs square root

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I am trying to understand which of the following two functions grows faster:

$$f(x)=n^{0.2}$$

$$g(x)=\log^5(n)$$

I plotted this and $g(x)$ is a lot faster in growth than $f(x)$. Wolfram Alpha has claimed that $f(x)$ grows faster, which confuses me. I have heard that every $n^a$ with $a>0$ always grows faster than a $\log$, but does that also hold for a $\log$ set into power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(n)$ catches up with $g(n)$ at $n$ equal to around $10^{52}$. You need some patience! "...but does that also hold for a $\log$ set into power?": Yes.